# Is it possible to combine multiple commands in single webdriver http call?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Selenium from Java with a remote grid. When I find an element on a page I would like to retrieve its text, multiple attributes from this element, check whether it is displayed and whether it is enabled.

As far as I can see each thing I retrieve triggers a new remote call (to http endpoint of the webdriver). Since I know beforehand which values I'm interested in I would like to combine them in a single http call (as the call can be quite slow). Is this possible in Selenium with Java? Or even with the webdriver protocol?

To be clear: my problem is not finding an element based on multiple criteria in one go, I know how to do that. But *after* I find the element I want to know the values of multiple properties, and I want to gather these efficiently.

As far as I can see the protocol requires a separate call for each attribute value, the text, whether the element is displayed and whether it enabled. For me this means for instance 6 round trips to the server, where one could suffice if I were able to 'multiplex' all data I would like to retrieve in a single call.

Is there a way to optimize retrieving multiple details/properties of an element once I found it?

Comment: i only can think about a javascript workaround but nothing to bundle commands from selenium server side

Comment: I don't think there is any predefined class/method from where you can get those info. Probably you need to create one custom class/method and using driver instance you need to gather info regarding values of multiple properties which you want.

Answer (score 0):

On solution to have less calls between the driver and server could be to use some javascript in the context of the client side/window.

You can write something like

```
combinedObject = driver.executeScript("function(domelement) {
  return { abc: domelement.getAttribute('abc'), efg: domelement.getAttribute('efg'), hij: domelement.getAttribute('hij') };
}",foundedElement);
```

This can reduce the number of calls between driver and server.

If it makes sense to mix some javascript functions with your java code is your decision.

Comment: Nice idea. and `domelement` should be `arguments[0]`, correct?

Comment: No. In Java Context foundedElement is the WebElement and passed to the executeScript function. The Webdriver convert this element as a DOMElement in the Javascript/Client side. And it's passed as an argument to the javascript function. (in the example as the parameter domelement).

Comment: But you can use also arguments[0]. It's pointing to same object as domelement.